# Mutiny - Kafka writes happening sequentially

Tags: apache-kafka, quarkus, mutiny

I am new to Quarkus. I am trying to write a REST endpoint using quarkus reactive that receives an input, does some validation, transforms the input to a list and then writes a message to kafka. My understanding was converting everything to Uni/Multi, would result in the execution happening on the I/O thread in async manner. In, the intelliJ logs, I could see that the code is getting executed in a sequential manner in the executor thread.  The kafka write happens in its own network thread sequentially, which is increasing latency.

```
@POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Multi<OutputSample> send(InputSample inputSample) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

       //deflateMessage() converts input to a list of inputSample
        Multi<InputSample> keys = Multi.createFrom().item(inputSample)
                .onItem().transformToMulti(array -> Multi.createFrom().iterable(deflateMessage.deflateMessage(array)))
                .concatenate();

     
        return keys.onItem().transformToUniAndMerge(payload -> {
            try {
                return producer.writeToKafka(payload, mapper);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        });
    }
```

```
@Inject
@Channel("write")
    Emitter<String> emitter;

Uni<OutputSample> writeToKafka(InputSample kafkaPayload, ObjectMapper mapper) throws JsonProcessingException {
        
        String inputSampleJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(kafkaPayload);
        return Uni.createFrom().completionStage(emitter.send(inputSampleJson))
                .onItem().transform(ignored -> new OutputSample("id", 200, "OK"))
                .onFailure().recoverWithItem(new OutputSample("id", 500, "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"));
    }
```

I have been on it for a couple of days. Not sure if doing anything wrong. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Multi is intended to emit sequential items, if you want parallel processing try creating multiple Unis and then use Uni#combine to join them.

Comment: To enable concurrency, use `merge` instead of `concatenate`. However, be careful as Kafka often requires things to be ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi is intended to be used when you have a source that emits items continuously until it emits a completion event, which is not your case.

From Mutiny [docs](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/getting-started/creating-multis):

> A Multi represents a stream of data. A stream can emit 0, 1, n, or an
> infinite number of items.
>
> **You will rarely create instances of Multi yourself** but instead use a
> reactive client that exposes a Mutiny API.

What you are looking for is a `Uni<List<OutputSample>>` because your API you return 1 and only 1 item with the complete result list.

So what you need is to send each message to Kafka without immediately waiting for their return but collecting the generated Unis and then collecting it to a single Uni.

```
@POST
public Uni<List<OutputSample>> send(InputSample inputSample) {
    // This could be injected directly inside your producer
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // Send each item to Kafka and collect resulting Unis
    List<Uni<OutputSample>> uniList = deflateMessage(inputSample).stream()
            .map(input -> producer.writeToKafka(input, mapper))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // Transform a list of Unis to a single Uni of a list
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // Mutiny API fault...
    Uni<List<OutputSample>> result = Uni.combine().all().unis(uniList)
            .combinedWith(list -> (List<OutputSample>) list);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*mutiny* as any other reactive library is designed mainly around data flow control.

That being said, at its heart, it will offer a set of capabilities (generally through some operators) to control flow execution and scheduling. This means that unless you instruct *munity* objects to go asynchronous, they will simply execute in a sequential (old) fashion.

Execution scheduling is controlled using two operators:

- `runSubscriptionOn`: which will cause the code snippet generating the items (which is generally referred to upstream) to execute on a thread from the specified `Executor`
- `emitOn`: which will cause subscribing code (which is generally referred to downstream) to execute on a thread from the specified `Executor`

You can then update your code as follows causing the deflation to go asynchronous:

```
Multi<InputSample> keys = Multi.createFrom()
    .item(inputSample)
    .onItem()
    .transformToMulti(array -> Multi.createFrom()
            .iterable(deflateMessage.deflateMessage(array)))
    .runSubscriptionOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultExecutor()) // items will be transformed on a separate thread
    .concatenate();
```

### EDIT: Downstream on a separate thread

In order to have the full downstream, transformation and writing to *Kafka* queue done on a separate thread, you can use the `emitOn` operator as follows:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Multi<OutputSample> send(InputSample inputSample) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return Uni.createFrom()
            .item(inputSample)
            .onItem()
            .transformToMulti(array -> Multi.createFrom().iterable(deflateMessage.deflateMessage(array)))
            .emitOn(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)) // items will be emitted on a separate thread after transformation
            .onItem()
            .transformToUniAndConcatenate(payload -> {
                try {
                    return producer.writeToKafka(payload, mapper);
                } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return Uni.createFrom().<OutputSample>nothing();
            });
}
```

Comment: is it possible to do each kafka write on a different thread, as that is the part that is increasing latency?

Comment: I updated my answer with an end-to-end flowable path.